# Untar files with python and extract certain files with tarfile.extractall() python

Tags: python, file, tar

I am trying to untar files with tarfile.extractall() so that I can get a subset of the images in the directory by using the optional parameter 'members'.

I have an array containing the filenames of all the files that I would like to extract that I am passing in here but from what I understand they should be TarInfo objects. How can I turn my array of file names into an array of TarInfo objects? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
t = tarfile.open(filename, 'r')
t.extractall(out_dir, filearray)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a requirement to use `extractall`, you first need to generate a list of `tarinfo` objects that match with `filearray`

```
members = [ x for x in t.getmembers() if x.name in filearray]
```

You can then pass that into `extractall`

```
t.extractall(out_dir, members)
```